# How to do a typed parameter package class?

Tags: c++, templates

I need to package a fixed number of values of arbitrary types in a class.  Then I need to be able to pass each parameter through a switch according the their type.  The types of the parameters are basic C types and pointers to stuff (a specific and limited number of "stuff"), so nothing complicated.

That "Parameter" class needs to be light (in space as well as in processing).

This is an example of how I need to use it:

```
void MyFunc( const Parameters &Params )
{
// for loop
switch( Params(0).GetType() ) {
  case MY_INT_TYPE: int ValInt = Params(0).Get<int>(); ...
  case MY_PTR_TO_MY_STUFF1: MyStuff1 *ValS1 = Params(0).Get<MyStuff1*>(); ...
  ...
  }
}

Parameters MyParams(2);
MyParams.Set<int>(0, 123);
MyParams.Set<MyStuff1*>(1, &SomeClassInstance);
MyFunc( MyParams );
...
MyParams.Set<float>(0, 123.456);  // The same variable in the same scope
MyParams.Set<int*>(1, &Val);
MyFunc( MyParams );
```

Of course I can specialize for all types manually and store in a union, that is the brute force approach.  I keep thinking there is an easier way to do this, but can't figure it out.  I can use type traits to store the type info, but I am stuck for the value.  And casting the value is not an option.

Any pointer (figurative pointers that is)?

Comment: Does `boost::variant` meet your purpose?

Comment: It has many problems for my needs, but the biggest is that I cannot use an external library.  Nonetheless I will scour its implementation to see if I can find inspiration, thank you.

Comment: It would seem like using class for each type and letting polymorphism do its magic would suit your needs; it sometimes out-performs switch-cases too. Have you considered this? Are there any special constraints that prevent you from going this way?

Comment: I don't see how an array of polymorphic classes would get me around the use of the switch case presented above.  That is not a switch case inside the class.  With specialized classes there is no overhead in space or performance.  Polymorphic classes will have a performance and a size hit.  Also the use case would also dramatically differ from the simple example above.

Comment: What will you use `ValInt` and ValS1` for after you extract them from the parameter list? Can you give some example code for the way you need to use them?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding last your comment I give you next answer :)

```
class ParamsProcessor
{
    // custom parameter reciever for type T1
    template<>
    public ParamsProcessor& in<T1>(const T1& o)
    { ... } 

    // custom parameter reciever for type T2
    template<>
    public ParamsProcessor& in<T2>(T2 t2)
    { ... } 

    // default parameter reciever
    template<class T>
    public ParamsProcessor& operator in(const T& o)
    {
       // some generic way if the project allows
       ...
       return *this
    } 

    void Process()
    { ... }
};


ParamsProcessor pp;
pp.in<T1>(0,123)
  .in<T2>(0,123.456)
  .in("asds");
  .Process();
```

Sure better if each overload will process itself.
I am really hope that my answers will cover your needs.

Comment: That is a very interesting way to pass the parameters to the class, but I would still need to define a function for each type accepted.  This is exactly what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Also I definitely wanted an explicit typing of the values (in and out of the class), that way it is much easier to maintain the code and debug.

Comment: You do not have to define a function for each type because you have template. Sure if you have reason to use template specializations than maybe will be better to use any other method name instead of operator<<. I'll edit the post regarding your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway there will be at once one switch if you will not use run-time polymorphism. If you will use static polymorphism than you need either specialization or switch.

Its good approach to use type2enum and enum2type mapping:

type2enum:

```
// preparition
template<class T> type2enum();
#define TYPE2ENUM_SPEC(TYPE, ENUM) \
template<> type2enum<TYPE>() \
{ return ENUM; }

enum { T1enum, T2enum, T3enum }
TYPE2ENUM_SPEC(type1_t, T1enum);
TYPE2ENUM_SPEC(type2_t, T2enum);
TYPE2ENUM_SPEC(some_third_type_t, T3enum);
```

and backward enum2type:

```
// preparition
template<int Enum>
struct enum2type;
#define ENUM2TYPE_SPEC(ENUM, TYPE) \
template<> struct Enum2Type<ENUM> \
{ typedef TYPE type_t; }


// and generic macro
#define CREATE_TYPE_MAPPING(TYPE, INTEGER) \
#define TYPE2ENUM_SPEC(TYPE, INTEGER) \
#define ENUM2TYPE_SPEC(INTEGER, TYPE)
```

and the sample of code:

we have Type1, Type2, Type3 and enum:

```
enum {T1, T2, T3};

CREATE_TYPE_MAPPING(Type1, T1);
CREATE_TYPE_MAPPING(Type2, T2);
CREATE_TYPE_MAPPING(Type3, T3);
```

than use it for mapping type to enum:

```
int typeId = type2enum<Type1>();
```

or constant enum to type:

```
typedef Enum2Type<ConstEnumType>::type_t some_t;
```

and for runtime enum to type you use something like:

```
template<class ObjT>
void DoWithTypeIdValue(int enumValue, const ObjT& obj)
{
    switch(enumValue)
    {
       case enumType1:
           obj.do<Enum2Type<enumType1>::type_t>();
           break;
       case enumType2:
           obj.do<Enum2Type<enumType2>::type_t>();
           break;
       case enumType3:
           obj.do<Enum2Type<enumType3>::type_t>();
           break;
       default:
           assert(!"Unknown type constant");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant by "specializing for all types manually", and it is not what I wanted, even though this is what I ended up implementing.  There was no satisfying way around it.

Comment: Understood. See next solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Another way that allows to get rid of switch is use enum and array of functors:

```
enum TheTypes { T1, T2, T3, TheTypesCount};

boost::function<void (const Parameters &Params)> Processors[] = {
    boost::bind(&T1::ProcessingMethod, t1Obj, _1),
    boost::bind(&T2::ProcessingStaticMethod, _1),
    boost::bind(RawFunction, _1)
};
```

And that allows you substitute intrusive stitch with simple construct:

```
void MyFunc( const Parameters &Params )
{
    // for loop
    Processors[Params(0).GetType()](Params(0));
}
```

Congratulaions!

If you are maniac than will discuss next approach.
What about creating static decorator (mixin) for automaticially do following:

- indexing features
- store feature processing functor
- forming an array of features

Comment: Thanks.  That is a nice simplification of the switch, but it is overly complex for my needs and the switch was not really the problem.  I wanted to simplify the definition of the parameter class.  The switch was just an example of how it could be used.

Comment: Than you could use solution like c++ streams.

Comment: I mean overriding of operator << for each type that you need.

Answer (score 0):

An ideal implementation would use a variant type (e.g. `boost::variant`) parameterised by the valid set of parameter types. Here's an example of how to use a variant type to solve the problem:

```
typedef Variant<int, MyStuff1*> Parameter;

int main()
{
    MyStuff1 SomeClassInstance;

    Parameter MyParams[2] = { 123, &SomeClassInstance };

    int ValInt = MyParams[0].Get<int>();
    MyStuff1* ValS1 = MyParams[1].Get<MyStuff1*>();
}
```

And here's an example of how to implement a variant type, if you can't use `boost`.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename U>
struct MaxSize
{
    static const size_t value = sizeof(T) > sizeof(U) ? sizeof(T) : sizeof(U);
};

struct ValueBase
{
    virtual ~ValueBase()
    {
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct ValueGeneric : ValueBase
{
    T value;
    ValueGeneric(const T& value) : value(value)
    {
    }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Variant
{
    typename std::aligned_union<MaxSize<T1, T2>::value, T1, T2>::type storage;

    Variant(const Variant&); // not copyable
    Variant operator=(const Variant&); // not assignable
public:
    template<typename T>
    Variant(const T& value)
    {
        new(&storage) ValueGeneric<T>(value);
    }
    ~Variant()
    {
        static_cast<ValueBase*>(static_cast<void*>(&storage))->~ValueBase();
    }

    void Set(const T1& value)
    {
        SetImpl(value);
    }
    void Set(const T2& value)
    {
        SetImpl(value);
    }
    void Get(const T1& value)
    {
        this->~Variant();
        new (this) Variant(value);
    }
    template<typename T>
    bool IsA() const
    {
        return typeid(T) == typeid(*static_cast<const ValueBase*>(static_cast<const void*>(&storage)));
    }
    template<typename T>
    T& Get()
    {
        assert(IsA<T>());
        return *static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(&storage));
    }
    template<typename T>
    const T& Get() const
    {
        assert(IsA<T>());
        return *static_cast<const T*>(static_cast<const void*>(&storage));
    }

private:
    template<typename T>
    void SetImpl(const T& value)
    {
        this->~Variant();
        new (this) Variant(value);
    }
};
```

This implementation is intended as an example and only supports two types - it would be relatively easy to extend to support more. You would want to use template-parameter-packs and move-constructors to achieve the cleanest and most efficient implementation.