# switch depending on object type

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wondering if there is a way of doing the following in the better way (easier to read, less verbose).

I have the object Foo which has it concrete Foo implementation types lets call them Foo1 .. FooN.

I also have the string table of descriptions of the foo for instance Foo1 "bars the Foo1". What I want to do is some kind of the type check depending on the actual type of Foo coming to function. Currently I do:

```
std::string fooUtils::translate(Foo * foo){
   if(typeid(foo) == typeid(Foo1){
      return "bars the Foo1";
   }
   else if
     ...
}
```

I was wondering whether there is any better way of doing so.

The first one I think of is storing the std::map < std::typeinfo, std::string > - this is the solution I am keen on going for but I am unaware of any side effects of having the type info as a key to the map (are there any?). I was also wondering if there is anything to  compare types in less verbose way for instance boost::is_type< Foo1 , foo > or something like this.

Comment: You can't store `typeinfo` directly in a container, since `typeinfo` has no public constructors.  Gotta get crafty.

Comment: Search for the type2enum template function on Google. It creates an enum from each of your types (your classes), so you can use the enum in your switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `type_info` search utility:

```
template<class T, class...Ts>
std::array<std::decay_t<T>, sizeof...(Ts)+1> make_array( T&& t, Ts&&...ts ) {
  return {{ std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<Ts>(ts)... }};
}
template<class F, class T, size_t N>
std::array<T, N> sorted( std::array<T, N> arr ) {
  std::sort( begin(arr), end(arr), F{} );
  return arr;
}
struct p_type_info_sort {
  bool operator()( std::type_info const* lhs, std::type_info const* rhs ) const {
    return lhs->before(*rhs);
  }
};

template<class...Ts, class T>
std::type_info const* which(T const& t) {
  static const auto table=sorted<p_type_info_sort>(make_array(
    (&typeid(Ts))...
  ));
  auto r = std::equal_range( begin(table), end(table), &typeid(t), p_type_info_sort{} );
  if (r.first==r.second) return nullptr;
  return *r.first;
}
```

you do a `which<A, B, C, D>(*a)` and it returns which of the list of types the instance `*a` matches exactly (dynamically).  It does this by returning a `type_info const*`, and `nullptr` if it fails to find a match.

Now this is usually a bad idea.  The above does exact matches, only.  Usually if you have that much polymorphism, you will want to put it into the interface, and failing that, you probably have some other design flaw.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aef53a0af16acb8d)

Comment: I think it will not work because the number of the subclasses... Also every time you are adding the subclass you would need to add it in your which<> parameter list.

Comment: @cerkiewny yes?  You asked for a `switch` between types.  `switch`s require each `case` to be listed.

Comment: Oh I didn't get your answer at first, so you would just modify the std::map<typeinfo, string> to std::map<typeinfo *, string>, do your template selection in the function, then based on the type info selected you would take the string out of the std::map? but how are you creating the std::map<typeinfo *, string>?

Comment: @cerkiewny Ah, I get it.  Well, the fact that my array only contains `typeinfo*` is not important.  I could unpack a traits class and have a `class_name<T>::str` or `some_func<T>()` or `some_functor<T>{}()` stored beside each entry.  Then a failure for `some_func<T>()` to compile (or the traits or the functor) would generate an error at compile-time (that you are missing the string for some class).

Comment: this is actually better then expected, it is nice way to enforce that someone creating the new class will provide the string for it. very nice solution.

Answer (score 8):

That's what `virtual` member functions are for:

```
std::string fooUtils::translate(Foo * foo) {
    foo->translate();
}
```

With:

```
struct Foo {
    virtual std::string translate() const { return "base"; }
};

struct Foo1 : Foo {
    std::string translate() const override {
        return "bars the Foo1";
    }
};
```

Comment: how would you go about iterating through all the types then? You would need some kind of collection of all the possible subtypes of the type?

Comment: @cerkiewny There is no iteration, no collection of subtypes. We just use dynamic dispatch to pick the right type at runtime.

Comment: maybe I haven't asked the question clearly enough, but I want to stay with my current approach, so store the string connected with a type somehow and select from a collection depending on incoming type, what you proposed is totally different approach. It will not work for me as I need to have the access to all the inforamtion together.

Comment: @cerkiewny: You said you want "a better way, less verbose" and that it has to be just like your existing code?  That doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @cerkiewny This does "store the string connected with a type somehow." It does it in a very efficient, simple, non-brittle way too.

Answer (score 0):

In this thread, you can find the type2enum conversion and the backward enum2type conversion: [How to do a typed parameter package class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748165/how-to-do-a-typed-parameter-package-class)

Extract of the answer:

```
template<class T> type2enum();
#define TYPE2ENUM_SPEC(TYPE, ENUM) \
template<> type2enum<TYPE>() \
{ return ENUM; }

enum { T1enum, T2enum, T3enum }
TYPE2ENUM_SPEC(type1_t, T1enum);
TYPE2ENUM_SPEC(type2_t, T2enum);
TYPE2ENUM_SPEC(some_third_type_t, T3enum);
```